# Convert the given set into roster notation:

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Problems:**

Find $A$, where

1) $A = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x^4 - 1 = 0\}$

2) $A = \{x \in \mathbb{C} \mid x^4 - 1 = 0\}$

**Attempt:**

Solving the equation:

$x^4 - 1 = (x^2)^2 - 1^2 $

$= (x^2 - 1)(x^2 + 1) $

$= (x-1)(x+1)(x^2 + 1) $

$= (x - 1)(x + 1)(x^2 - i^2) $

$= (x-1)(x+1)(x-i)(x+i) $

**1) Since $x$ is defined as a real number in this case, $A= \{1,-1\}$.**

**2) Since $x$ is defined as a complex number in this case, $A= \{1,-1, i, -i\}$.**

Is my work correct?

Comment: Yeah this is correct you got it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your answer and notation are correct.